# WPF DataGrid запретить выход из ячейки при ошибки валидации данных

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет, работаю с WPF DataGrid и возникла такая проблема: есть исходный класс Student и таблица с данными DataGrid. List устанавливается в качестве источника данных для DataGrid, а поля класса Student биндятся к полям DataGrid. Если пользователь введёт ошибочные данные в поле DataGrip - допустим в рейтинг студента типа double введён строку - то DataGrid отреагирует следующим образом:
[image: Ошибка при вводе букв в числовое поле]

Ячейка выделяется красным и пользователь не может изменять другие ячейки, пока не исправит ошибку. Также при нажатии ESC восстановится старое значение.
Мне нужно сделать проверки для других полей - допустим, валидация Email с помощью регулярных выражений и проверка ФИО на пустоту. Я сделал следующее:

Класс Student:

```
class Student : IDataErrorInfo, IEditableObject
{
    private bool inEdit = false;

    private Student tmpStudent;

    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public string StudentGroup { get; set; }

    public string StudentEmail { get; set; }

    public double StudentRating { get; set; }

    public DateTime StudentCreatedDate { get; set; }

    public bool StudentIsHaveGrants { get; set; }

    public Course StudentCourse { get; set; }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "StudentName":
                    if(StudentName == "")
                    {
                        return "Поле \"ФИО\" должно быть заполнено!";
                    }
                    break;
                case "StudentGroup":
                    if (StudentGroup == "")
                    {
                        return "Поле \"Группа\" должно быть заполнено!";
                    }
                    break;
                case "Email":
                    if (StudentEmail == "")
                    {
                        return "Поле \"Email\" должно быть заполнено!";
                    }
                    break;
                case "StudentRating":
                    break;
                case "StudentCreatedDate":
                    break;
                case "StudentIsHaveGrants":
                    break;
                case "StudentCourse":
                    break;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            string error;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            error = this["StudentName"];
            if (error != string.Empty)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(error);
            }

            error = this["StudentGroup"];
            if (error != string.Empty)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(error);
            }

            error = this["Email"];
            if (error != string.Empty)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(error);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString()))
            {
                return sb.ToString();
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        if (inEdit)
        {
            return;
        }
        inEdit = true;
        tmpStudent = new Student();
        tmpStudent.StudentName = StudentName;
        tmpStudent.StudentGroup = StudentGroup;
        tmpStudent.StudentEmail = StudentEmail;
        tmpStudent.StudentRating = StudentRating;
        tmpStudent.StudentCreatedDate = StudentCreatedDate;
        tmpStudent.StudentIsHaveGrants = StudentIsHaveGrants;
        tmpStudent.StudentCourse = StudentCourse;
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        if (!inEdit)
        {
            return;
        }
        inEdit = false;
        tmpStudent = null;
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        if (!inEdit)
        {
            return;
        }
        inEdit = false;
        StudentName = tmpStudent.StudentName;
        StudentGroup = tmpStudent.StudentGroup;
        StudentEmail = tmpStudent.StudentEmail;
        StudentRating = tmpStudent.StudentRating;
        StudentCreatedDate = tmpStudent.StudentCreatedDate;
        StudentIsHaveGrants = tmpStudent.StudentIsHaveGrants;
        StudentCourse = tmpStudent.StudentCourse;
    }
}
```

И XAML DataGrid'а:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="StudentsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ФИО" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=StudentName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Группа" Width="100" Binding="{Binding StudentGroup}"/>
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Email" Width="*" Binding="{Binding StudentEmail}">
                    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DataGridHyperlinkColumn_Click"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Рейтинг" Width="80" Binding="{Binding StudentRating}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Дата зачисления" Width="130">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StudentCreatedDate}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Наличие стипендии" Width="150" Binding="{Binding StudentIsHaveGrants}"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Курс" Width="70" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding StudentCourse}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CourseEnum}}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Поведение получилось похожее, но в таком случае, ячейка просто выделяется красным и пользователь может изменять другие ячейки. При ESC старые данные также восстановятся.
[image: Моя реализация]

Собственно, сам вопрос: как заблокировать выход из ячейки если данные невалидны (и сохранить возможность по ESC восстановить данные)

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981358/keep-cursor-in-cell-after-cancel-in-wpf-datagrid-celleditending-event-with-mvvm/60290452#60290452),  быть может это поможет. Если кратко, то в обработчике события `PreviewKeyDown` ячейки нужно установть `e.Handled` в `true` при нужном вам условии.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, как добиться желаемого: для DataGrid нужно определить обработчики событий PreviewKeyDown и PreviewLostKeyboardFocus со следующим содержимым:

```
private void StudentsGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var errors = (from c in
               (from object i in StudentsGrid.ItemsSource
                select StudentsGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(i))
                      where c != null
                      select Validation.GetHasError(c))
          .FirstOrDefault(x => x);
        if (errors)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if(e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                StudentsGrid.CancelEdit();
            }
        }
    }

private void StudentsGrid_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var errors = (from c in
               (from object i in StudentsGrid.ItemsSource
                select StudentsGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(i))
                      where c != null
                      select Validation.GetHasError(c))
          .FirstOrDefault(x => x);
        if (errors)
        {
            if(e.OldFocus is TextBox textBox)
            {
                if (Validation.GetHasError(textBox) && !e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Escape)){
                    if (!e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Escape))
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StudentsGrid.CancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PreviewKeyDown позволит отловить нажатие Enter и остаться в той же ячейке в случае ошибки, по нажатию клавиши ESC - отменить изменение. PreviewLostKeyboardFocus блокирует выход из ячейки с помощью кнопок мышки в случае ошибки.